# How to store values in a C structure without losing them when calling structure

Tags: objective-c, static, struct

I have a C (Objective-C) structure defined:

```
struct ResultadoVentaPUP{
    NSString *autenticadoPorPin1;
    NSString *autenticadoPorPin2;
    NSString *tipoPago;
    NSString *importe;
};
```

Then I declare a variable of this type **globally** (at top of the file):

```
ResultadoVentaPUP resven;
```

In a function I set values for this structure, for example:

```
resven.importe=@"12.45";
```

but when I try to view the content of "importe" in another function from the same file), ir returns (null).

```
NSLog(@"Result: %@",resven.importe);
```

What am I doing wrong? should I define the struct with 'static'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing Obj-C objects in a C structure is a rather bad idea nowadays anyway, with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), it is not even allowed any longer (the compiler will complain if you do that). Why not using an object instead? If you don't want to use assessor methods because you fear the overhead, just use an object with public ivars. Public ivars are bad IMHO, yet a struct is pretty much the same as an object with public ivars.

```
@interface ResultadoVentaPUP : NSObject
{
    @public
    NSString * autenticadoPorPin1;
    NSString * autenticadoPorPin2;
    NSString * tipoPago;
    NSString * importe;
}
@end

@implementation ResultadoVentaPUP
@end

ResultadoVentaPUP * resven;


void someFunction () {
    resven = [[ResultadoVentaPUP alloc] init];
    resven->importe = @"12.45";
}

void someOtherFunction () {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@",resven->importe);
}
```

This code will also work nicely if you use ARC and sooner or later every project should migrate to ARC in the near future (as soon as it can drop support for OSX/iOS versions without ARC support).

Comment: Good advice along with a functional solution. +1

Comment: yeah, I did what you said. but the problem is that I set:
resven = [[ResultadoVentaPUP alloc] init] inside an implementation, and I have to show: resven->importe outside of this implementation, so XCode returns: bad access when trying to NSLog that...

What can I do? thanks!

Comment: @user1897162: I'm not sure what exactly you are saying here, yet I think the problem could be, that the Class Interface is unknown outside this file. You'll have to put the "interface declaration" into an own .h file and import this .h file wherever you need to access that interface (otherwise the code in another file has no knowledge of the public ivars of this class).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your declaration should be `struct ResultadoVentaPUP resven;`. This works for me:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct ResultadoVentaPUP{
    NSString *autenticadoPorPin1;
    NSString *autenticadoPorPin2;
    NSString *tipoPago;
    NSString *importe;
};

struct ResultadoVentaPUP resven;

void func1() {
    resven.importe = @"12.45";
}

void func2() {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", resven.importe);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    func1();
    func2();

    [p release];
}
```

And I would be remiss if I didn't include the caveat that any time you are using global variables you should seriously be reconsidering your design.

Comment: thank you! i'll try Mecki's procedure due to ARC problem...I'll try your response too! :D